# Tabularray warning: Table width is too small

Tags: warnings, tabularray

I tried to use the `tabularray` package to create an environment for my CV template, which works fine. However, I get an error: `Package tabularray Warning: Table width is too small, need 8.0036pt more!` I was considering sharing my template on Overleaf, but this requires the document to have 0 warnings (not included overfull or underfull \hboxes). So, my question is simply: **how do I get rid of this error?**

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=23mm,right=23mm,
bindingoffset=0mm, top=20mm,bottom=20mm}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\newenvironment{CV_table}{%
    \begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tblr}{%
    colspec={Q[l,0.2\textwidth] Q[l,0.5\textwidth] Q[l,0.24\textwidth]},
    column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    rowsep=0.5\baselineskip}%
    }
    { 
    \end{tblr} 
    \end{table}
    }

\begin{document}
``Tabular eqvivalent'':
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.5\textwidth} p{0.24\textwidth}}
    \textbf{a} & b & c \\[0.7\baselineskip]
    \textbf{d} & e & f
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

What i get using tblr:
\begin{CV_table}
    job name 1 & job description & {Date \\ Location} \\
    job name 2 & job decription 2 & {Date 2 \\ Location 2} 

\end{CV_table}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

**Edit:**

Is it possible to remove the space (row separation) for the last row only? The row extends a little too long down. I have marked the section of the row I want to be removed in this image:

[image]

Comment: `p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.5\textwidth} p{0.24\textwidth}` is `0.94\textwidth+6\tabcolsep` wide which may be more or less than `\textwidth`  depeding on the values. It is better with `tabular` or `tblr` to specify values that add up to `\textwidth` if you want a full width table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want eXtensible columns; the numbers in the specification denote the relative proportions.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  left=23mm,
  right=23mm,
  bindingoffset=0mm,
  top=20mm,
  bottom=20mm,
  showframe,% comment for production version
}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\newenvironment{CV_table}{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}\noindent
  \begin{tblr}{
    width=\textwidth,
    colspec={@{} X[l,2] X[l,4] X[l,3] @{}},
    column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    rowsep=0.5\baselineskip
  }%
}{\end{tblr}\par\addvspace{\topsep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{CV_table}
    job name 1 & job description & {Date \\ Location} \\
    job name 2 & job description 2 & {Date 2 \\ Location 2} 
\end{CV_table}

\end{document}
```

Note that you *don't want* to use `table`. Modify the amount of space in `\addvspace` in order to change the spacing around such tables.

[image]

Comment: I used table because if I wrote some text, the text appeared to the right of ``tblr`` which was messy. I avoided this using ``table``.

Comment: @Vebjorn That's the wrong tool. As you see, I used `\par`.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the row extension below the text for the last row (see post edit)?

Comment: @Vebjorn Sorry, I don't know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, but I could not find it elsewhere, so I decided to still post the question and just ansewer it myself to help others who want to fix this error.

I simply included `width=1.1\textwidth,` in the specification of `tblr`, which removed the error. Here is the *new* definition of the `CV_table` environment:

```
\newenvironment{CV_table}{%
    \begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tblr}{%
    colspec={Q[l,0.2\textwidth] Q[l,0.5\textwidth] Q[l,0.24\textwidth]},
    column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    rowsep=0.5\baselineskip}%
    }
    { 
    \end{tblr} 
    \end{table}
    }
```

Comment: the code you show doesn't have the change you describe? Making the table 1.1\textwidth wide would not be an option in documents that need to observe specified margins. Also using `[h]`  will usually generate a warning that it is being changed to `[ht]`